# Guess the output of a c program

Tags: programming-languages

I have come across a c program like this .

```c
int main()
{
  int a,i=4;
  int z=5;
  a=--i+ --i+ --z; 
  printf("%d %d",a,i);
  
  return 0;
}
```

What will be the output? I need some explanation.

Comment: Undefined behaviour. Look it up.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make it tidy.

```
int main() {
    int a, i = 4;
    int z = 5;
    a = --i + --i + --z;
    printf("%d %d", a, i);

    return 0;
}
```

As gnasher729 said, it is undefined (by the standard)

This means it is entirely compiler-dependent.

But, you said to take a guess.  Working left to right, the following has a certain logic to it:

1. “- - i”: this decrements i before its value is used. So, it becomes 3.
2. “- - i”: this again decrements before it is used. So “i” is now 2.
3. “- -z”: “z” is decremented before use. So, “z” becomes 4.
4. “a” = 3+2+4 = 9
5. printf("%d %d", a, i) will print i and z, therefore 2 and 9

After using 3 compilers, I got the answer 3 times of 2 and 8.

That gives a better idea of undefined.